# Django's USE_L10N does not work

Tags: django, internationalization, locale, localization

I already set USE_L10N = True in settings.py

But in following view:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma

dev view_name(request):
     output = intcomma(123456)
```

Output is always "123,456" for all locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intcomma only respects the localization settings in Django 1.4 and higher.

In the meantime, remove `intcomma` and enable [`USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#use-thousand-separator).

Note that this enables thousand separators on *all* integers.

Answer (score 1):

I think *intcomma()* does the same for all locales:

```
def intcomma(value):
    """
    Converts an integer to a string containing commas every three digits.
    For example, 3000 becomes '3,000' and 45000 becomes '45,000'.
    """
    orig = force_unicode(value)
    new = re.sub("^(-?\d+)(\d{3})", '\g<1>,\g<2>', orig)
    if orig == new:
        return new
    else:
        return intcomma(new)

intcomma.is_safe = True
register.filter(intcomma)
```

You can modify this function and pass the separator as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing that in a template, you can set in settings.py:

```
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR=True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR='.'
NUMBER_GROUPING=3
```

making the 3 changes above, DECIMAL_SEPARATOR will automaticaly become ','. But you can also set it:

```
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR=','
```

this way you dont need humanize, but i guess this will affect all your applications under this settings.py file.

Answer (score -1):

```
import locale
locale.format("%d", 123456, True)
```